# Having created my android app in Android Studio, can I deploy the next version of the app using a different code base created from Xamarin?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Let's say I created my android app using Android Studio in Java.
On version 2, I want to use Xamarin using C# (either Native or Forms).
Is it possible to do that?
Practically that is a lot of rewriting but my current situation is I can only use Android Studio but not Xamarin. I am thinking if I need to wait until I can use Xamarin or just create the first version of my app in Android Studio.

Comment: along with the codes, another most important thing is AppSigning and keys. make sure you learn about them too before deploying your app. Otherwise you will not be able to update the app even if you manage to recreate it in some other platform.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Is it ever possible to have a different code base, Java first version of the app, then C# 2nd version of the app?

Comment: yes, as long as the package id is the same and the same signing key is used, Android will just see it as a new version of the same app

Comment: @Jason Even if I use Xamarin.Forms? (I have no experience with any mobile development stack)

Comment: Yes - the development stack should not matter if the package name and signing key are the same

Comment: deleted my answer, down-voted and close-voted... because I felt ridiculed. while speaking of "big things" alike Java and C# and an imaginary "app", where the signing key would matter, appears slightly delusional - while not having the least experience with neither of the stated environments.

Comment: @JoshuaSantos have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...because this question it is not only "unclear what you are asking", but also "too broad" would be a certain reason to close it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I don't know man, I did the "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" tip. Its a yes or no question but you keep on bringing up C++, native and other stuff. Its just a yes or no question from an inexperienced developer. The other people here have answered it by saying yes/no and you keep on explaining that C++ stuff. Have a nice day though.

Comment: @JoshuaSantos programming is all about being able to make a point ...read your question again, which hints for that you've spent little time in prior research - and flattering them (an obvious behavior) does not help you learning, just alike reading only the half if it and then filling up the rest with believe won't.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes I don't know much that is why I'm asking LOL. Viewing your profile seems you are easily triggered so I'll let you be :D

Comment: @JoshuaSantos what I'm basically trying to tell is, that well-written questions are much easier to answer - and in general less time consuming for everybody involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** you can have different code bases per **VERSION** of a single application provided:

1) You use the same [Signing Key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

2) You use the same [Application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)

So you can write an app in Java designated as version 1. Provided you use the same *SIGNING KEY* and *APPLICATION ID* you can replace it with a Xamarian app as version 2.

Complications can arise if you are trying to maintain or update data in a SQLite database or share data between different versions with different architectures.

Comment: Thanks man! This is the answer that I needed :D. Also thanks to @Jason